# If or If-Else Statement Error

Tags: java

I am trying to write an If or If-Else Statement that protects the program when an integer value is not entered when prompted. I keep getting the error message: '.class' expected.

```
  System.out.println("Type the name of your destination: ");
      destination = keyboard.nextLine();

      System.out.print(destination + " is how many miles away?");

      miles = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (miles != int);
      {
         System.out.println(miles + " is not valid. I will use 100 for the number of miles.");
      }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: why don't you use Integer.parseInt()? If it is not a valid integer then it throws NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a keyword and cannot participate in conditional expressions.

There is also a spurious semicolon after your `if` statement, which acts as the controlled statement, so  the following block is unconditional.

Comment: Explain to me then how `miles != int` is a valid statement that would compile and execute properly.

Comment: I don't intend to debate things I haven't actually said.

Comment: Then your answer still does not fix the problem.

Comment: @EJP Legend meant that `int` is a **reserved keyword**, so the expression inside `if` is invalid.

Comment: @informatik01 I am perfectly aware of what he meant thank you. But he imputed that I had said otherwise when I hadn't, and I have no intention of wasting my time discussing statements I haven't made.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, just in case you accidently missed that

Answer (score 2):

This can not compile:

```
if (miles != int);
```

You are comparing a variable with `int`,which is a type. The compiler suggest you to add .class, so you can obtain the class object, but it is not correct either.

You want to know if an integer value is not entered, but in that case what would happen is that nexInt() would throw a `InputMismatchException`. What you should do is to check with hasNextInt() if the user is inputing an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error that you are getting is because `int` is a keyword. You cannot use it as an identifier.

If you would like to check if a `Scanner` has an `int` ready for reading, use `keyboard.hasNextInt()` in your condition:

```
int miles;
while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {    
    System.out.println(keyboard.nextLine() + " is not valid. Please enter a different number.");
}
int miles = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a ; after the if statement.

You also have it checking what the user inputs to an int which is not a number. might  want to fix that with a number and it should work... from what i can remember from class.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (miles != int);
```

You can't test if a number is an int like that. You also have a semi colon at the end of this line (which should be removed). However, there's actually no reason to have that line at all. Because you wrote:

```
miles = keyboard.nextInt();
```

miles has to be an int. Otherwise an exception will be thrown by Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start this by saying that you need to do a Java Tutorial.  Your code is full of basic mistakes.

---

(Assuming that `keyboard` is an instance of `Scanner` ...)

Mistake 1 - You cannot use a type name or keyword (e.g. `int`) as a value.

Mistake 2 - You can only use `==` to compare integer values (like the value of `miles`) with other numbers.

Mistake 3 - You shouldn't put a semicolon after `if (condition)`.  What you have written will compile, but it actually means "if the condition is true, then execute the empty statement".  Then you've followed that with a block ... that will be executed **unconditionally**.

Mistake 4 - In fact, if `keyboard.nextInt()` encounters something that isn't a valid integer, it will throw an exception; e.g. `InputMismatchException`.  If you want to print out an error message, you need to **catch** that exception.

Mistake 5 - Obviously you didn't check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) for the `nextInt()` method ...

---

To recap ... you are making so many mistakes because you haven't done the tutorial ... or you've been skipping lectures or something.